# Add user input to existing user input in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$summe
$input1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input one'
$input2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input two'
$summe = $input1 + $input2
echo $summe
```

I want to add `$input1` to `$input2`. For example, if the first input is `12` and the second input is `3`, the result should be `15`.

For me, however, the result is `123` if I do it with a plus sign. So it simply concatenates the two numbers one after the other. How do I get my desired result?

Thank you in advance. Greetings Nick

Comment: Can you translate to English? You can try Google Translate at least.

Comment: @Mathias It's discouraged to translate Questions. One doesn't know if the author is able to respond to clarification questions. Also, I think you may have missed a backtick. (And the title)

Comment: @Scratte thanks, updated the title and code formatting issue. I was not aware translating questions was discouraged, do you have a meta posts discussing this?

Comment: @Mathias I do :) This is the canonical linked from the FAQ Index: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680). I suggest you leave this one though. Rolling is back would be a disservice to answerers.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell decides on operator behavior based on the *type* of the left-hand-side operand:

```
$input1 + $input2
#  ^
#  |
# Behavior of `+` depends on what type of data this is
```

`Read-Host` returns a `[string]`, so PowerShell goes "+ on strings means concatenation, let me do that!"

Convert the left-hand side operand to a numerical type and it'll work:

```
$sum = [int]$input1 + $input2
echo $sum # 15
```

Answer (score 0):

folgendes sollte funktionieren:

```
$summe
[int]$input1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input one'
[int]$input2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input two'
$summe = $input1 + $input2
Write-Host $summe
```

Das was vom Benutzer kommt ist Text, dementsprechend wird dieser auch "addiert", i.S.v. zusammengefügt.
Du kannst jedoch `$input1` und `$input2` explizit als ganze Zahl (Integer) definieren. Dann werden die Zahlen auch addiert, das Ergebnis ist immer eine ganze Zahl.
Möchtest du auch Dezimalzahlen verwenden empfiehlt es sich statt `[int]` `[double]` oder `[float]` zu verwenden. ACHTUNG: "1,5" ist nicht zulässig, "1.5" jedoch schon.

LG

Ehh...you changed the language, so do I:

the following should work:

```
$summe
[int]$input1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input one'
[int]$input2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'input two'
$summe = $input1 + $input2
Write-Host $summe
```

What comes from the user is text, accordingly this is also "added", i.e. put together.
However, you can explicitly define `$ input1` and `$ input2` as integers. Then the numbers are also added, the result is always a whole number.
If you also want to use decimal numbers, it is advisable to use [double] or [float] instead of [int] '. ATTENTION: "1.5" is not allowed, but "1.5" is.